# SQL Postgres compare data in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table 'charges', in this table I have an id, a description, a price and a location. 
What I am trying to do is generate a query that will match the descriptions in the table and give me both pricing columns for one location. The best I have been able to do so far gives me duplicates between the two locations:

```
select charge1.description, charge1.price price1, charge2.price price2
from charge charge1 inner join
(
    select * from charge
) charge2
on LOWER(charge1.description) = LOWER(charge2.description) 
where charge1.id != charge2.id 
and charge1.location != charge2.location;
```

This will give a result like:

```
Description | price1 | price2
-----------------------------
burger      | 5      | 10
burger      | 10     | 5
steak       | 40     | 20
steak       | 20     | 40
```

I would like a result like:

```
Description | price1 | price2
-----------------------------
burger      | 5      | 10
steak       | 40     | 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select c1.description, c1.price as price1, c2.price as price2
from charge c1 inner join
     charge c2
     on LOWER(c1.description) = LOWER(c2.description) 
where c1.id < c2.id and c1.location <> c2.location;
```

I don't think the comparison on `location` is necessary, but without sample data I'm not sure if that's true.

Comment: Location is important here, I would like to compare location a's prices with all the other locations that have the same food item. The query you provided comes up with a comparing its self.

Comment: @that_guy . . .What is `id` repeated?  In any case, just add the filter back in.